# SQL update with a LAG

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following update that updates a record based on a prior record -

```
    WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        patient, 
        start,
        CASE 
        WHEN 
            ISNULL(start, '') = '' 
            AND cd = '3'
            AND LAG([thru_dt]) OVER (PARTITION BY [patient] ORDER BY cast(claimno AS int) ASC) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, -30, thru_dt), 112) AND thru_dt
            AND LAG([cd]) OVER (PARTITION BY [patient] ORDER BY cast(claimno AS int) ASC) = '30'      
        THEN LAG([start]) OVER (PARTITION BY [patient] ORDER BY cast(claimno AS int) ASC) 

        WHEN ISNULL(hhstrtdt, '') = '' AND
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY patient ORDER BY cast(claimno AS int) DESC) = 1
            AND LAG([cd]) OVER (PARTITION BY [patient] ORDER BY cast(claimno AS int) ASC) = '30'     
            AND LAG([thru_dt]) OVER (PARTITION BY [patient] ORDER BY cast(claimno AS int) ASC) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, -30, thru_dt), 112) AND thru_dt
        THEN LAG([start]) OVER (PARTITION BY [patient] ORDER BY cast(claimno AS int) ASC) 
        ELSE start
    END AS new_start
    FROM table
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET start = new_start
```

This query only updates one record at a time. For example, if I had this input -

```
start       patient     cd
20190307    497863693   30
NULL        497863693   30
NULL        497863693   30
NULL        497863693   30
```

To update, all 3 rows with a NULL `start` with the value of the first row, I would have to run the query 3 times.

The output would be -

```
start       patient     cd
20190307    497863693   30
20190307    497863693   30
20190307    497863693   30
20190307    497863693   30
```

Is there a way to get the query to update all rows for the above patient instead of it doing it one by one? I could keep a count of the NULLs in the table and make the update stop running once the no.of NULLs in the table stopped decreasing but that does not seem like a good way of doing it.

Comment: Use `max()` instead with same partition and order by

Comment: I don't think I can use MAX(). I need the current rows record to be the prior rows record. @Sujitmohanty30

Comment: From your example it doesn't seems to be different values if I use `lag` or `max`. Anyway that's my understanding at the moment. Would be nice if you provide the actual sample data instead the out put of the query and then atleast two different scenarios what to update as expected result.

Comment: @Doe . . . Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would be helpful.  Your query does not correspond to the sample data.

Comment: are you after the [The Last non NULL](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle) ?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov No, I am after the last value regardless of if it is a NULL or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative max for this.  If I understand correctly, you want to reset `NULL` values on rows with cd = 30 to latest `start` value when `cd = '30'`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(start) over (partition by patientid order by cast(claimno AS int)) as imputed_start
      from t
      where cd = '30'
     )
update toupdate
    set start = imputed_start
    where start is null or imputed_start <> start;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to update the whole table at once would be something like this

```
with rn_cte as (
    select * , row_number() over (partition by patient order by (select null)) rn
    from tTable)
update tTable
  set start=NULl
where rn>=2;
```